# Are jumping ships feasible? (Not jump drives, but ships that jump)

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, planets, gravity, ships

As mentioned above this is not about jump drives, this is about ships that physically jump.

Writing science fiction, trying not to handwave *too* much, so I want to check if this is a feasible tech.

Orbit Jumpers are ships used on small planets with <1 gravities and/or asteroids large enough for a gravitational pull. Essentially, they have electromagnetic legs that build up kinetic energy and release it all at once, extending the piston-like leg toward the ground. Similar to a railgun in design, but much less power. Once out of orbit, omni-directional thrusters are used to maneuver.

Is this possible?

Edit: Thanks for the answers everyone! It seems I may have to drop my ship idea. Luckily it’s not super integral to the story, I just hadn’t seen anything like it before, but now I know why. Lol

Comment: We can't answer your second question suspension of disbelief is a function of how well a story is told, and facts are presented not how realistic those facts are. One of my favorite spaceships in recent memory is a tree that powers itself by burning magic items.

Comment: Very true. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: Do you have inertial damping technology/magic?  Without it, I can't see this being a useful solution without *very* long legs.

Comment: I highly recommend playing a little Kerbal Space Program if you want to write about orbital mechanics realistically. It's pretty crazy how much your intuition can change just by playing with orbits hands on a bit. For example, one of the things you learn very early on in that game is that going UP just isn't enough; orbiting means going SIDEWAYS really, really fast. A leg just isn't going to have enough traction to shoot you sideways fast enough. (Then additionally there's air resistance and the fact that if your orbit starts from the ground, it hits the ground again one orbit later.)

Comment: Maybe if you lived on *The Little Prince*'s planet, where the diameter is only about 3 times the height of a person...  Of course that probably wouldn't have enough gravity to stand on without constantly going into orbit when you trip on a rock.  Or if it did, it'd basically be a neutron star and not exactly conducive to princes living on it...

Comment: @BeeWadd46290 since you mention asteroids, then it's totally possible (though not for anything with gravity strong enough to walk on). Check out the sub-surface sample procedure of Hayabusa2 which happened in 2019 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa2

Comment: @DanielWagner Disagree--you can reach low Kerbin orbit with a big vertical kick (you'll have to do much of it above the atmosphere) and a very small burn, it's just slow and inefficient.  Burn straight up until your apoapsis is just below the Hill Sphere, then coast.  At apoapsis adjust your periapsis to 60km (the edge of Kerbin's atmosphere is 70km.)  Wait until your apoapsis drops to the desired altitude then circularize.  In practice you can't actually jump through the atmosphere, but this stunt requires an atmosphere to shed your extra energy.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Gaining altitude to reduce fuel usage is the second thing you learn. Maybe somebody out there learned those lessons in the other order but I would bet easily 99% don't. ^_^

Comment: @DanielWagner The point is that if you have enough altitude you can get your horizontal velocity with a tiny burn, you don't need the huge burns rockets do.  The idea was what would happen with a catapult launch if you could get around the drag on the way up.  If NASA could trade 9km/sec of rocket burn for 18km/sec of catapult launch they would be ecstatic.  Note that even without aerobraking if you have a spaceship-flinger it's cheaper to fling it far out and use your rockets to lower the apoapsis than to simply burn to orbit.

Comment: Most of the answers below seem to ignore the fact that your planet has much less gravity than Earth....

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**If you can't survive crash-landing from space, you can't survive jumping to space.**

An interesting and useful property of orbital trajectories is that they are reversible in time. If you want to start from the ground and launch yourself into space with one sudden impulse, that is essentially the same as a time-reversed version of starting from space and stopping at the ground with one sudden impulse - i.e., crash-landing. The feasibility of survivably jumping into space is basically the same as the feasibility of survivably crash landing from space (ignoring drag effects).

On bodies with earth-like gravity, that will require speeds of several km/s when jumping/crashing, which will not be survivable unless you have an absurdly long piston arm to spread the acceleration over time. This would only really be feasible on very small bodies with low gravity and no atmosphere, where the required takeoff velocity is measured in m/s rather than km/s. The limiting factor is the crew's survivable acceleration. You could work backwards from survivable acceleration values and the piston extension time to estimate your maximum takeoff speed - if this speed is not greater than the escape velocity of the body you're leaving, you'll be coming right back. Drone ships that don't have to protect squishy meatbags could handle much higher accelerations and would be better suited to such a launch design, although you'd still likely require a surface gravity of considerably less than 1G.

Comment: Of course if you *do* have any appreciable atmosphere, crash-landing safely becomes quite feasible, while reverse-crash-landing becomes even more impossible.

Comment: Just to calculate this through: World record accelleration experienced by human is 46Gs, or ~460m/s^2. Pluto has escape velocity of 1.21km/s, or 1210m/s. Meaning you need to accelerate for 3 seconds with 46G, travelling a distance of 460*1.5=700m. Absurdely long Piston is sadly accurate.

Comment: On something like Phobos, jumping is quite feasible, at least from a purely mechanical perspective.  The problem is hang time: a simple human-legs-powered jump will send you a kilometer or so up, with half an hour or so to enjoy the scenery before you need to figure out how to land.

Answer (score 28):

## No, not without making astronaut-salsa

Earth's escape velocity is around 11 kilometers per second. This is *blisteringly* fast.

To calculate the acceleration that would be needed to achieve that speed in a single jump, you can use a kinematics formula:

$$\frac{v^2}{2\Delta x} = a $$

Where $v$ is target velocity and $\Delta x$ is the length of the "Jump Legs" on your spacecraft. If we plug in numbers for an ascent out of Earth's gravity well and using a leg-length of, say 100 meters, we get a necessary acceleration of around **60000G** (The instantaneous human LD50 is around 75G). This would kill any humans aboard and probably break the ship too; it's more than bullets experience when being fired out of a gun. Also, the atmospheric friction would be extreme, most likely rendering the entire ship to a fine burnt powder

*Even if* the planet you're "jumping" from has no atmosphere and is several times smaller than Earth, there is no configuration where something is both considered a "planet" and has survivable launch accelerations.

Answer (score 7):

When it comes to space everything comes down to delta V, how much ability something has to change it's velocity. For instance it takes roughly 9.4 km/s of delta V to get to low earth orbit from earth. Getting to the moon will take roughly another 6 km/s of delta V. If you were going to jump from the earth to the moon you'd need to leave the ground going 15 km/s from a standstill. This is ignoring all the energy you'd loose due to air resistance, which increases exponentially based on velocity.

So anything near earth gravity, or with an atmosphere is definitely out.

What's far more likely is instead of having every ship contain all the mechanisms necessary to jump to the proper speed, (which will also need to be accelerated to the target speed), is to use a fixed launcher to do the "jumping" for the ships. This is effectively the idea behind using mass drivers on the moon to ship mined material back to earth.

Answer (score 7):

### Possible yes. Feasible no.

> Similar to a railgun in design, but much less power.

Exactly. You have mostly answered your own question.

Also taking this to apply to places with gravity below 1/3g

#### Analogous to gun launch.

Essentially the question is asking the feasibility of a gun launch system. Or a rocket that just has one bang.

To be maximally effective, such a system would have very high forces on take off/launch. People don't really handle prolonged 20+g forces on their bodies. This is a known problem with these systems so usual solution is to increase barrel length, increase acceleration time.

#### Most of the time in space its just a drag.

But once the ship is away from the a space-body those legs are dead weight. They don't help with propulsion. But they need to be moved to the next destination of the ship.  It will cost fuel to move them to a place where they are useful again.

### Possible/feasable scenario

Unmanned exploration unit that would jump around a moon or some other low mass planetoid. Perhaps more versatile then wheels. Less expensive then legs. Such a system would jump from location to location as it explored. The jumps would allow views from elevation and allow crossing of rough terrain. That is the jumping would be the primary mode of transport.

Answer (score 2):

If you have very long legs, yes. Spreading out the force over a long distance means you need less power (and will incur less $v^3$ air resistance.

If you wanted short legs they'd have to be telescopic, but then you'd have to fill them with gas as they extend, which would incur friction at the entry point. You could suck air in at the top though a wide aperture and then blow it out at the bottom through as small aperture as the legs contract.

Of course the energy involved implies a great deal of heat expenditure. Where are you getting this energy from? If you can handwave that away and manufacture telescopic sections which are very thin and light, then this might be feasible.

It might work best as a launch assist, to release a vessel which can rocket the rest of the way with lower fuel requirements. The telescopic legs would return to the ground after launch, and remain connected to the ground during extension so they can be driven by a local power station.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1: GRAVITATIONAL SLINGSHOTS**

Potentially, you could have a ship that uses centrifugal force and the gravitational pull of a planet to sling itself around a planet. This maneuver has been done by real-world interstellar vessels before.

**OPTION 2: ONE BIG GUN**

If you aren't afraid of making your novel seem really outlandish and comical, you could have some kind of huge Electromagnetic Propulsion cannon that launches a propulsionless 'vessel' of sorts at incredibly high velocities out of the planet's gravitational towards a distant target and lets sweet, sweet inertia do the rest. Problems with this could include tiny amounts of friction piling up over incredibly long trips and slowing progress to a crawl and meteors and gravity fields knocking the pod off course or destroying it.

Both options, however, are incredibly slow without some way to achieve FTL. It could take billions of years to reach a distant planet or star. You could compensate for this with some kind of stasis, or with generation ships.

Comment: Note that gravitational slingshotting only works if you're already not orbiting the body in question. You can't actually slingshot out of orbit; you accelerate as you near the planet by exactly the same amount to decelerate leaving the planet, and end up at the same speed and altitude you started at. Also, real-world "interstellar" vessels don't exist. We've barely left our own heliopause. Though that's not really relevant.